# error accessing the property of an object inside an array in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular

I have this array

[image]

When I debug to compare the content of its path properties in Chrome I see this for example

[image]

But when I try this in Angular

[image]

I get this error

error TS2339: Property 'path' does not exist on type 'string'.

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your first line you assign `this.pathOfertas.filter(...).paths` to `arrayFiltrado`. So you can just remove the paths in the last lines because you already have your path in the variable.

Comment: in arrayFiltrado I have an array of anonymous objects with one property path, and I need to access that property like I can in debug mode in Chrome. arrayFiltrado[index].includes('001-18') does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have solved declaring arrayFiltrado like an array of objects with that path property

```
let arrayFiltrado:{path:string}[]=[];
arrayFiltrado = this.pathOfertas.filter(p => +p.year == 2018)[0].paths;
for (let index = 0; index < arrayFiltrado.length; index++) {
  if (arrayFiltrado[index].path.includes('001-18')) {
    return "uu";
  }
}
```